# Centralized Grade Access System for University

Tags: web-services

I'm looking for a system that I can easily deploy to a server which performs a very simple function:

- Allow university administrators update grades of students for courses they've taken
- Allow students to check their grades online

I've heard of Moodle which accomplishes the above, but it does much, much more than what is needed. I'm hoping for a more lightweight solution than Moodle.

Comment: How about a Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: While that would work, there are so many different courses offered with individual students taking just 5 or 6, that it would become unwieldy to actually fill and use.

Comment: Schoology! Edmodo!